# LXD with Cloud-init, `cloud-init status --wait` is hanging or running forever

Tags: 22.04, lxd, cloud-init

I followed the [Quick-start tutorial with LXD](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/lxd.html), and it went well until `cloud-init status --wait`, it is running forever.
`cloud-init status` returned `status: running`.

But when I tried it with `multipass`, it returned `status: done`.
Note: Ubuntu 22.04

> $ lxc version:
> Client version: 5.20
> Server version: 5.20

What am I missing? What do I need to do?

Comment: Running the same instructions works for me. Probably best to open a bug at https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/issues and include the tarball generated from running `cloud-init collect-logs --include-userdata` in your container.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience.

It looks like the problem is `snap.lxd.activative.service`

`$ systemctl `

```
  UNIT                       LOAD         ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION                         
  snap.lxd.activate.service  not-found  failed failed  snap.lxd.activate.service           
  systemd-remount-fs.service  loaded    failed failed  Remount Root and Kernel File Systems

```

Comment: This seems to be the issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1878225